# I want to proxy Exchange through my Ubuntu server. How can I do this?

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-outlook, apache-http-server, proxy, exchange

I opened up ports 80 and 443 on my Time Capsule to go to my Ubuntu 14.04 Server machine. I have a splash page-kinda for my intranet. It's internal.domain. I have Exchange 2013 on another server (Windows Server 2012 R2), and I want to be able to access it from mail.domain. How can I configure my setup so that Exchange is proxied through Apache on the Ubuntu server?

Thanks,
—Emmanuel